# Checkbox makes select input that uses a foreach required with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i have a registration form with these inputs: Options that you can check with checkboxes and selects with the extraoptions. both use a foreach. 
So, i want that if you check an Option, the select with the extra options for that option will be required

I have tried using jquery to make the extraoption select required, but now when i check one of the checkboxes, it makes all selects required. and if i uncheck all checkboxes, the selects are still required.

**Jquery**

```
if(this.checked){                           
$('.extraoption').attr('required', 'True');
}
else{                           
    $('.extraoption').attr('required', 'False');
}
```

**html**

```
<label>Options</label><br>
@foreach($option_array as $option)  
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="option" id="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}" value="{{ $option->exa_id }}" {{ isset($cache) ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')  : (old() ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '') : ($registration ? (in_array($option->exa_id, $registration_options) ? 'checked' : '') : '')) }} >
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_prijs }}" class="option_prijs_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
<label>{{ $option->exa_naam }}</label> <label class="exa_prijs">  €{{ $option->exa_prijs }} </label>    
</div>

<select name="extraoptions_{{ $option->exa_id }}" class="form-control extraoption">
<option></option>
@foreach($option->extraoptions as $extraoption)
<option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}" {{ ($inschrijving ? (in_array($extraoption->eos_id, $inschrijving_options_extra) ? 'selected' : '') : '') }}>{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<br>
@endforeach
```

Anybody can help me out with this one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use element id instead of class, in your code it will set all element has a class name 'extraoption' required.

Comment: i added id="extraoption" to the extraoption select, and now only the first extraoptions select is required when i check any checkbox